# MUST iOS live video use HLS?

Tags: ios, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I'd like to make an app that can play live video and start to learn hls, rtmp, rtsp.But documentation of Apple require developer use hls for live video, or will be rejected for distribution.Does any one use rtmp in your app and success to sale in AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses RTMP. So assuming your user base is about a billion people you should be good to go. Otherwise stick to HLS.